# autocomplete input text

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

I want to be able to autofill my address input text box when i select a name. i am able to autocomplete the names. So when i select a name, it should auto fill the respective address in the address input. How do i do this? Thank you

**HTML**

```
<div class="form-group">
<div class="col-lg-10">
<input type="text" class="typeahead form-control" id="name" placeholder=" Name" name="name" >

</div>
</div>

</div>


<div class="col-sm-6">
<div class="form-group">


<div class="col-lg-10">
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="address" placeholder="  Address" name="address" >


</div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
        var path = "{{ route('autocomplete') }}";
        $('input.typeahead').typeahead({
            source: function (query,process){
                return $.get(path, {query:query},function (data)
                {
                    return process(data);
                })
            }

        });


     </script>
```

Comment: take a look at [this](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/06/checkout-faster-with-autofill)

Comment: @FeMachine, isn't this a chrome feature?

Comment: theoretically not, implementations may vary. The attribute is supported in all browsers (but IE), the values is not guaranteed, in the article it's linked [this other one](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-control-infrastructure.html#autofill) that describes the standard.